# How to customize python libz.so.1 reference in linux system

Tags: python, matplotlib, zlib, libpng

I'm currently using linux system.
I have a simple python GUI code that uses matplotlib  library. My IDE is spyder(Anaconda) and this python code work well.
The problem is when I run this code on linux console ( $ python my_matplotlib_gui.py)
(Of course other simple python codes work well.)
This command give this error code:

```
======================
Import error: /lib/libz.so.1: version 'ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /user/mysys/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/libpng16.so.16)
======================
```

I recognized that this problem arouse from the fact that the /lib/libz.so.1 is linked to the zlib_1.2.7.  The low version.

But there are ~/anaconda3/lib/zlib_1.2.11 exists! That's why code worked well when I run this code in Spyder.

So I want to ask: Is there any way to use "~/anaconda3/lib/zlib_1.2.11"  when I run python code on linux console?

Thank you.

Comment: You can also run this program on the Linux console with Anaconda (no Spyder).

Comment: It looks like your Python envionment variables (*PATH*, *PYTHONPATH* etc.) are messed up in the Linux console. Activate Anaconda properly (so the Anaconda *python* program will run your script, and *zlib* will work), and then run your script as usual (*python my_matplotlib_gui.py*).

Comment: To get help with debugging, you may want to add the output of `env | grep -E 'PYTHON|PATH|CONDA'`; `type conda`; `type python` to the question.

Comment: Just adding "import zlib" to py file solved this problem lol. thank you!